# Efficiently generate Map<String, String> from List<String>

Tags: apex

I have a List of strings elements delimited by ','

```
List<String> myList = new List<String> {'Training,Train'};
```

I want to use add these 2 values (the actual number may be less or more - not fixed) as keys of a map with same value without iterating over this list. How can I achieve this by using split on list element.

The output should be something like below:

```
Map<String, String> resultMap = Map<String, String> {
'Training' => 'Cat1',
'Train' => 'Cat1'
}
```

The only constraint here is that I want to avoid looping over list returned using String.Split(',') method on myList elements as I'm already inside of a loop.

Comment: Nested loops are not inherently evil, and a loop is the right tool to use when you have a collection of things to go through (regardless of whether or not the size of the collection is constant). As long as you don't have queries/dml in loops and don't have something like `if(outerLoopVar.field1 == innerLoopVar.field2)` in the inner loop, then it's fine and we don't have the tools available to really do anything else.

Comment: If you can show us what you've tried, someone might be able to make some basic suggestions like "this thing never changes between iterations of the outer loop, so you should move it out of the loop entirely".

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can possibly pull this off would be with JSON manipulation.

```
String[] myList = new String[] { 'Training,Train' };
Map<String, String> results = new Map<String, String>();
for(String item: myList) {
    String[] keys = item.split(',');
    Map<String, String> keyMap = (Map<String, String>)
        JSON.deserialize(
            '{"'+String.join(keys,'":"Cat1","')+'":"Cat1"}',
            Map<String, String>.class
        );
    results.putAll(keyMap);
}
```

However, this is no more efficient than looping over the individual elements, and will actually perform worse over larger payloads. You should consider this answer more academic in nature, as I would not recommend using this in production-quality code due to the performance concerns.

There's still a hidden inner loop anyways: `String.join`. Just because we're not explicitly using a for loop doesn't mean that one doesn't exist.